# Convert Time.zone.now to number OLE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I need convert the DateTime to OLE, Actually I have this code

```
  def self.convert_time(t=42941.6102054745)
    Time.at((t - 25569) * 86400).utc
  end
```

but this converts to DateTime now I want this solution :

```
def self.date_time_ole(dt= Time.zone.now)
# her convert to number ole from datetime
end
```

could you please help me ?

Comment: What is a "number OLE"?

Comment: Converts the value of this instance to the equivalent OLE Automation date.

Comment: An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component     is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24

Comment: I don't know if this is correct Time.zone.now.to_f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's `Date` class subtraction returns number of days between 2 dates, so you just need to subtract your "custom epoch" (December 30, 1899 at midnight) from the other date:

```
ole_epoch = DateTime.new(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0)
now = DateTime.now # => 2017-08-18 21:03:28 UTC
(now - ole_epoch).to_f # => 42965.87741847492
```

and that should be OLE and you can also just add it to go the other way:

```
ole_epoch + 42965.87741847492 # => Fri, 18 Aug 2017 21:03:28 +0000
```